# Why does ASP.net write whitespace at the end of the output from my ASHX file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, ashx

I've written an ASHX generic handler to output XML.  However, for some reason, ASP.net is appending numerous whitespace characters to the end of the output which breaks the XML.

My code looks like this:

context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

```
        XmlSerializer oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ModelXml[]),new XmlRootAttribute("rows"));
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.Xml.XmlTextWriter tw = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(ms2,new System.Text.UTF8Encoding());
        oSerializer.Serialize(tw,models);
        string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms2.GetBuffer());
        tw.Close();
        ms2.Close();

        context.Response.Write(s.Trim());
        context.Response.End();
```

When I run this code thru the debugger, I see that the string `s` does indeed contain the XML data with NO WHITESPACE.  However, when I point Internet Explorer at this file, I get the following error:

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'http://localhost:5791/XXXXX.ashx'.
```

When I view the page source in Notepad, I see that the file begins with the correct XML, but there are numerous spaces appended to the end.  If I remove these spaces, the XML file works fine with my browser and applications.

Why is ASP.net appending these spaces to my output and what can I do about it?

Comment: What does your XML look like?

Answer (score 1):

Switch from MS2.GetBuffer() to MS2.ToArray().  You are reading the buffer from the MemoryStream, which is preallocated for efficiency.  You want just the used data, not the whole buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of serializing to a `MemoryStream`, you should serialize directly to `Response.Output`.
This should solve the issue.